# Head thought reading by others, analyzing this hypothetical situation

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Suppose a person has a feeling that others can read their mind and thoughts.

Suppose others present themselves in certain ways.

How can a person discover what algorithms of data presentation the other people are following?

Since, others, do not have their head unconcealed, they, always, and eventually, present a net advantage.

This is a hypothetical situation, but, nevertheless, this does by no means mean that it cannot be analyzed, (even, philosophically), and that you can not provide some answers.

Thank you for your responses.

Thanks.

Comment: A felony? I assume that's a typo, not sure what word you meant to type.

Comment: i assume they are asking about moral insanity, and whether or not it is an excuse. depends on the situation i guess.

Comment: Could you rephrase that? As of right now I don't get what this question is about, sorry.

Comment: I think the OP means, suppose others can read a person's thoughts but theirs are concealed. Is this an advantage for the others? If the person were a good leader it would be an advantage for the leader and the others since his intentions would be communicated directly. I don't think he would be too concerned about the various mental algorithms of the others as long as they have email to send him updates.